# SQL insert command in oracle SQL developer works, but if i run it from a NetBeans java app i've made it does not

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I am working on an app (java) for reading/inserting/deleting from SQL database. I stumbled upon an issue where a command, ran in the app would not work, but if i insert it in oracle SQL developer, it would. The error i am getting is ORA-00944: SQL command not properly ended.

Code i am trying to run:

```
insert into narocilo_opravilo values(32, 1, (select max(id)+1 from narocilo_opravilo));
```

All of the previous inserts i have ran work perfectly fine, except this one. Any solutions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: no trailing ; in your java app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this

```
insert into narocilo_opravilo select 32, 1, max(id)+1 from narocilo_opravilo
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you!